# Load Components Dynamically React Js with load more button

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I'm new to React Js, so I can't find a solution to my problem by myself, please help me.

I'm working on a website with a blog page, blogs should be displayed dynamically on the page. When page loads I want it to have 4 blogs, and underneath there will be  button, so when the user clicks it, React should render and display the rest of the blogs.

My code so far looks like this:

``````
import { blogs} from "./blogs";

import { Blog} from "./Blog";


function BlogList() {
    const cardComponent = blogs.slice(0,6).map((blog, i) => {
        return (
            <Blog
                key={i}
                id={blogs[i].id}
                img={blogs[i].img.src}
                date={blogs[i].date}
                title={blogs[i].title}
                img2={blogs[i].img2.src}
                logoTitle={blogs[i].logoTitle}
                text={blogs[i].text}
            />
        );
    });

    return (
    <div>{cardComponent}</div>

)
}`````

**This code lets me display 6 blogs when the page is loaded, what I want to do is add "Load More" button under these already loaded 6 blogs, when the user clicks the button it should render and display another 4 blogs from "blogs", and again have Load More button.** Any help will be greatly appreciated,

Thank you.
``````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code shows a fixed amount of blogs (6). Instead of hardcoding the amount of visible blogs, you need to store it in a variable that you can change later. We will use `useState` for this. You also need to change the amount of posts based on a button press, so a button and an action is also needed.

```js
function BlogList() {
    // Starting number of visible blogs
    const [visibleBlogs, setVisibleBlogs] = useState(6)

    // Set the visible blogs to the current amount + 4
    // eg. if there are 10 visible post, clicking again will show 14.
    const handleClick = () => {
        setVisibleBlogs(prevVisibleBlogs => prevVisibleBlogs + 4)
    }

    const cardComponent = blogs.slice(0, visibleBlogs).map((blog, i) => {
        return (
            <Blog
                key={i}
                id={blogs[i].id}
                img={blogs[i].img.src}
                date={blogs[i].date}
                title={blogs[i].title}
                img2={blogs[i].img2.src}
                logoTitle={blogs[i].logoTitle}
                text={blogs[i].text}
            />
        );
    });

    return (
        <div>
            {cardComponent}
            <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
                See more
            </button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: This solution worked perfectly for me, it's exactly what I wanted to do, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
function BlogList() {

  const [maxRange, setMaxRange] = useState(6); 

  const loadMore = useCallback(() => {
    setMaxRange(prevRange => prevRange + 4);
  },[])

  const cardComponent = blogs.slice(0, maxRange).map((blog, i) => {
    return (
      <Blog
        key={i}
        id={blogs[i].id}
        img={blogs[i].img.src}
        date={blogs[i].date}
        title={blogs[i].title}
        img2={blogs[i].img2.src}
        logoTitle={blogs[i].logoTitle}
        text={blogs[i].text}
      />
    );
  });

  return (
    <div>
      {cardComponent}
      <button onClick={loadMore}>Load More</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

So you can just maintain the maximum number of currently displayed `Blog`s in `state` and increment it when the button gets clicked.

I used `useCallback` so that a new function doesn't get created when the component re-renders.